# Optimal Data Load Speeds

Tags: data, bulk-api

We are currently attempting to load a large amount of data, and are currently using the BulkAPI, with chunk size of 200 and batches of 2000.  Is there documentation anywhere that would outline the FASTEST POSSIBLE way to load data?  Time is an important factor in this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bulk API in concurrent fashion (multiple jobs running at the same time) is the fastest option. If you use Salesforce Data Loader, it will create multiple Bulk API requests/jobs and fire them in parallel for you (see [BulkAPI vs Dataloader?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91597/bulkapi-vs-dataloader) for details). To improve throughput, you can request [a temporary increase](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315571&type=1&mode=1) in API limits.